# Java orm framework

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, orm

Do someone know if there exists a framework for java where I don't have to implement the DAO but I need just to define the interface and it works like the groovy entities?

For example naming a method *findByPrimaryKey* it will autodetect the primary key and do the right thing.

I'm not sure but I remember I have seen something like this with Spring...Am I wrong?

Comment: Have you considered JPA (Java Persistence API)?

Comment: Take a look at http://ormlite.com/

Comment: I've used the JPA, but I remember I had to write the DAOs using it...I'm looking for something which I need just to create an interface and it will be create at runtime maybe with a proxy...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the Spring Data-JPA project . It has similar features to what you need . See their page [here](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa).

Here's a [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods) to their query methods . It think this is what you're looking for .

Answer (score 2):

There are two for Spring, both based on JPA

- [Hades](http://redmine.synyx.org/projects/show/hades)
- [Spring-Data-JPA](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa) (it is somehow the successor of Hades)

Comment: YEAH! it was spring data JPA...I don't know hades...I will take a look...do you know it? how is it?

Comment: I used Hades very often and I like it, but Spring-Data-JPA is its successor (Oliver Gierke how has written Hades, works now for Spring and write Spring-Data-JPA). I will switch to Spring-Data-JPA for new projects

Answer (score 0):

[sormula](http://www.sormula.org) may work for you also. CRUD operations are available without requiring any DAO implementions. It does not have auto primary key detection but one simple annotation defines the primary key(s).

Answer (score 0):

As of Grails 2.3.6, GORM is officially supported as a standalone module.  See the [release notes](http://grails.org/2.3.6+Release+Notes) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to consider ActiveJDBC: http://javalite.io/activejdbc. It was modeled after RoR ActiveRecord, and retains some of its dynamic behavior. However, in Java you cannot define new methods at run time, as there is no equivalent of `method_mising` from Ruby. There is plenty documentation you can follow: http://javalite.io/documentation