# Read from Postgresql DB object type passed as method parameter

Tags: java, postgresql, reflection

So what I'm wondering is if it's possible to make a generic Postgresql connection class where you could pass as a parameter the object type you'll want to read from the DB (as a string) and then actually read from DB and return the proper List of objects.

Something like:

```
class DbConnection{ 
    string type;

    public DbConnection(string objectType) {
        type = objectType;
    }

    public getConnection() {..}

    public List<Object> readObjectsDb() {
        ...
        return List<type> theObjects // type is the atually class type, no longer the string now
    }
}
```

Basically I'd be able to read from any Postgresql db with this class based on an input parameter, and knowing that the type I'm passing actually exists in my program.

Is it possible? Maybe with reflection somehow?

Comment: There are many libraries that will do this for you. Spring's [JdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) for example.

Comment: Looks good, I still don't understand how passing my type as a string would work in transforming the object list into the specific type I want it to be

Comment: The `query` method accepts a `RowMapper`. Write you own or use the built in `BeanPropertyRowMapper`.

Comment: You may find the responses to [this old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001547/java-orm-framework) useful.

Comment: This is iffy. If your return type is `List<Object>` what's the benefit of discovering the type? You'll lose that info instantly anyway. Why not just accept a `Class<T>` instead of the string name, get the name like `clazz.getSimpleName()` or whatever, and return `List<T>`?